# Does every AJAX page need to verify user logged in?

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am just beginning to learn AJAX and got stuck on this problem.

Problem:
I want to show log-in button or log-out button depending whether the user is logged in to my website or not.

One possible solution I can think of is to do AJAX call to the server(Java servlet) verifying if the user is logged in. Server would check the session and respond with JSON yes or no. Then I would display the correct button on the client side.

However above solution forces me to repeat this process on every single page I am going to have on my website. There's got to be a much nicer way to achieve this. Could someone advise me on this?

Comment: Don't see why you'd need to use AJAX for this at all. Can't you just conditionally render each button when the page is first loaded?

Comment: Look into spring security. You should send a cookie with the user's token for every request, not just once per page.

Comment: @AntP Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${loggedIn}"><a href="...">Logout</a></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><a href="...">Login</a></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Put this in your JSP, and thus geneate the appropriate button when the page is rendered. No need for AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

The common way to solve this is to use the browser cookies. Go read up on session cookies. :)

Comment: Security should be on server side not client side, so it should be based on server session not client side cookies.